# Retrieve a value from a form text field and set that value in another form text field using RJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to retrieve a value from a form text field and set that value in another form text field using RJS as the following (or in a better way!):

```
update_page_tag do |page|
  page.event.observe('text_field1_css_id', 'keyup') do |element|
    element << ... # Get and set a '@variable' value using the value in the 
                   # HTML textarea tag with id = 'text_field1_css_id'. The 
                   # '@variable' value should be accessible from the
                   # 'element.replace_html' method stated below
    element << ...
    ...
    element.replace_html (:text_field2_css_id), @variable.inspect
  end
end
```

**How can I do that using the *Prototype* framework?**

Comment: aren't you pushing RJS too far? this would be so easy and clear with pure Javascript...

Comment: @tokland - How can I do that using the 'element <<' statement?

Comment: I wouldn't know, I stopped writting RJS a while ago. Not that I want to convince you, but what I usually do is respond the AJAX request not with Javascript but with JSON data (or HTML, if I just have to fill the view) and then JS code (already in the client) uses it. This ensures isolation between client and server code. Sorry I cannot help you with your question. Anyway, why are you setting the observe there and not on page load?

Comment: @tokland **asks**: "Anyway, why are you setting the observe there and not on page load?" **My Answer**: That code is stated in the view file. @tokland **says**: "Not that I want to convince you, but what I usually do is respond the AJAX request not with Javascript but with JSON data (or HTML, if I just have to fill the view) and then JS code (already in the client) uses it." **My Question**: I understand a little bit... can you give me some more information (links, explanations, ...) on "isolation between client and server"?

Comment: http://www.ntecs.de/blog/articles/2006/12/18/rails-rjs-templates-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In prototype:

```
// /public/application.js
$('text_field_1_css_id').observe('keyup',function(event){
   $('text_field2_css_id').setValue($F(event.element));
});
```

---

For others who might be interested, if you're using jquery, you can probably use:

```
// /public/application.js
$('#text_field_1_css_id').keyup(function(){
   $('#text_field2_css_id').value($(this).value());
});
```